# How to remove/uninstall ghost unused cameras?

Tags: windows, windows-10, camera

I noticed in Microsoft Teams that I have a long list of camera even though I uninstalled Elgato Screen Link, EOS and the EpocCam is not connected.

How can I clean this list?

[image: camera]

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot of Device Manager showing which Cameras your system detects? Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I don’t have the imaging devices tab in the device manager

Comment: At least one of the devices that are still installed should show up in Device Manager.

Comment: Can you export the following registry keys `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{860BB310-5D01-11d0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}` and `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A3FCE0F5-3493-419F-958A-ABA1250EC20B}`

Comment: Using [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can you provide similar information has contained in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct4qq.png) screenshot?

Answer (score 4):

If you open regedit (win+r ; type regedit)
and search (ctrl+f) for the following keys

`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{860BB310-5D01-11d0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}` and `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A3FCE0F5-3493-419F-958A-ABA1250EC20B}`

Underneath those keys you'll find a subkey instances that'll contain all your devices including the obsolete one's. Remove those obsolete entries and teams should be looking nicer.
(Thnx Ramhound for the classes! I was looking as well)

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. Don't reference a comment, rather edit that information into your answer. (Comments might be deleted)

Comment: @DarkDiamond this resolved the issue for me, once integrated with the referenced comments (as of my edit)

Answer (score 0):

Move your cursor to the upper- or lower-right corner of the computer screen. Click the "Settings" charm to open the Settings sidebar. Click "Change PC Settings" to open the PC Settings screen. Click "Devices" and then click the scanner or camera in the Devices list that you want to remove. Click the "-" button and then click "Remove" to confirm that you want to remove the device. Windows removes the device.

Press the "X" and "Windows Logo" keys on the keyboard simultaneously to open the Quick Link menu. Select "Device Manager" to open the Device Manager window. Double-click "Imaging Devices" to open the list of imaging devices. Right-click on the scanner or camera and select "Uninstall." Click "OK" to confirm that you want to uninstall the device from your computer. Windows uninstalls the device from your computer.